# How to destring a date in Stata containing just the year?

Tags: stata

I have a string variable in Stata called `YEAR` with format `"aaaa"` (e.g. `2011`). I want to replace `"aaaa"` with `"31decaaaa"` and `destring` the obtained variable.

My feeling is that the best way to proceed could be firstly `destring`ing the variable `YEAR` and then adding `"31dec"`. To `destring` the variable `YEAR` I have tried the command `date` but it does not seem to work. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be best to describe your eventual goal here, as use of `destring` just appears to be what you have in mind as the next step.

If your goal is, given a string variable `year`, to produce a daily date variable for 31 December in each year, then `destring` is not necessary. Here are three ways to do it:

```
gen date = daily("31 Dec" + year, "DMY") 

gen date = date("31 Dec" + year, "DMY") 

gen date = mdy(12, 31, real(year))
```

Incidentally, there is no likely gain for Stata use in daily dates 365 or 366 days apart, as they just create a time series that is mostly implicit gaps. 
If your data are yearly, but just associated with the end of each calendar year, keep them as yearly and use a display format to show "31 Dec", or the equivalent, in output.

```
. di %ty!3!1_!D!e!c_CCYY 2015
31 Dec 2015
```

Detail. `date()` is a function, not a command, in Stata. We can't comment on "does not seem to work" as no details are given of what you tried or what happened. `daily()` is just a synonym for `date()`.